# Assertion error when using NSCollectionView with QLPreviewView

Tags: macos, nscollectionview, quicklook

I am using an `NSCollectionView` where each `NSCollectionViewItem` uses a `QLPreviewView` to get a rendering of a file's content.

(This is an attempt at a file browser for images and other previewable files.)

Initially, this works fine.

However, once collection items are getting re-used, I get an assertion error (both in 10.13 and 10.14):

```
[QL] Assertion failure (unreachable code) - [… MyPreviewView activated … doc:[QLPreviewDocument …]] is already activated
```

Apparently, before I can re-use a `NSCollectionViewItem`, the previously used QLPreviewItem needs to be set to *inactive* state somehow. How do I do that?

I've tried to send the `close` message to the `QLPreviewView` instance but that doesn't make a difference.

I also do not get a dealloc call on my `QLPreviewView` subclass, which suggests that the object is still referenced by something else, possibly the `QLPreviewDocument`, which then gets confused about the change of state.

I have made a demo project available on github: https://github.com/tempelmann/NSCollectionViewWithQLPreview

To test: Run it, then scroll down. When reaching items 50 to 60, the assertion will be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

The fix is to set `QLPrewiewView`'s `shouldCloseWithWindow` property to `NO`.

This, I suspect, tells the controller behind the scenes not to attach itself to higher level structures, i.e. tells it to remain self-sufficient.

So, adding this line to the code that sets up a new `MyPrewiewView` object in the sample code's `ViewController.m` file prevents the error:

```
qlView.shouldCloseWithWindow = NO;
```